# Typescript Error with Axios API response - array methods do not exist on response

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I am having an issue with an axios response and a typescript error -
The Error that i am getting is Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'ISearchServiceResponse'.

How do I tell typescript that the object that i want to work with is an array and not the axios response after it has come back from the server?

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (apiKey) {
      const getUserFilters = async () => {
        try {
          const res = await searchService.filters.get(apiKey)
        
          const responsesWithoutKeywordAsset = res.data
            .filter(item => !item.key.includes('BAR'))
            .filter(other => !other.key.includes('FOO')) 

        } catch (err) {
          console.error(err)
        }
      }
      getUserFilters()
    }
  }, [apiKey])



type Res<T> = Promise<AxiosResponse<T>>

export const searchService = {
  filters: {
    get: (apiKey: string): Res<SearchService.ISearchServiceResponse> =>
    axiosInstance.get(
        www.myapicall.com?aggregation=PAYLOAD_CATEGORY`,
        {
          headers: {
            'X-Api-Key': apiKey
          }
        })
  }
```

}

```
export namespace SearchService {
    export interface ISearchServiceResponse {
      data: Filters[]
     }
     export interface Filters {
        key:string
        value: string
      }
    
  }
```

Comment: `Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'ISearchServiceResponse'` means that `'ISearchServiceResponse'` is not an array, so you don't have to tell typescript that, you need to pass the right data, we don't know what `'ISearchServiceResponse'` looks like so we can't help.

Comment: Have you imported the AxiosResponse types from axios? Pretty sure `ISearchServiceResponse` should be extending `AxiosResponse` like so: `export interface ISearchServiceResponse extends AxiosResponse { data: Filters[] }`

Answer (score 0):

## General advice

I've personally never defined my interfaces directly using `AxiosResponse`.
Instead, I've made use of the generic methods in the Axios typings.

For example:

```
const response = axios.get<User[]>("/users");
```

In this case, response will have a type of `AxiosResponse<User[]>`.
Meaning that `response.data` has a type of `User[]`, which will have a `filter`-function.

## Your specific issue

If I read your code well, then `Res<SearchService.ISearchServiceResponse>` is equal to `Promise<AxiosResponse<SearchService.ISearchServiceResponse>>`.
If you unwrap the promise, then you're left with `AxiosResponse<SearchService.ISearchServiceResponse>`.

This means that `AxiosResponse` has a field `data` of type `SearchService.ISearchServiceResponse`.
This `data`, also has a `data` field as defined by your interface.

So a call to `response.data.data.filter` would work.
But I'd change the interface into something that makes more sense.

### Suggestion from comments

It was suggested in the comments (by @marita-farruggia) to let `ISearchServiceResponse` extend from `AxiosResponse` which would work.

However, I'd define it as follows:

```
interface ISearchServiceResponse extends AxiosResponse<Filters[]> {}
```

Note: you'd then need to change your definition of `Res<T>` to `Promise<T>` (which makes the `Res` type an unnecessary abstraction of `Promise` in my opinion).